# Adobe Reader accessing MS proofing tools

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I'm using Adobe Reader v11.0.0.7 
When I try to attach a document (txt, doc, or whatever), I get the message: 
"Your AutoCorrect file, MSO2057.acl, could not be saved.
The file may be read only, or you may not have permission to modify the file."

Sometimes Acrobat freezes and sometimes I can continue to use it after I've attached the file. I've verified this error on a few pc's.

I've noticed that WinWord.exe is *always launched and must be closed with the task manager after I try to attach a file to the PDF.

Question: Why is acrobat trying to access MS proofing tools and can I stop it?

Thanks

Comment: I can get around the error by:   
   1.Opening Adobe Reader.
   2.Edit-->Preferences
   3.Security Preferences
   4.Uncheck the "Enable Protected Mode at Startup" checkbox 
   (which is checked by default when installing 11.0.06 or greater)
 
This sucks lemons. You have to do this just to attach a file, then re-enable it, or your frozen.